# MS Access sub-sub forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access as a front end for a MySQL database. In it I have several tables, all based around the concept of a Household and People (one to many, respectively). From that there are several join tables (such as Ethnicity and Dietary Restrictions) which are many to many. I would like to be able to edit this from a single form in MS Access.

So far I have it set up so that I can edit the household information, view/edit all the people associated with it, and expand the person detail to view 1 (out of 3) of the join tables associated with that person record. I cannot figure out how to get all 3 tables to be visible, does anyone know how to do this?

[image: One join table shown in the expansion.]

Comment: It is nearly always worth taking the time to create forms and subforms, rather than relying on datasheets, which is what you show. The main form would show a single record from the main table with various subforms related by link child and link master fields in either single or continous form view, positioned on tabs, if necessary for ease of use.

Comment: Unless if I misunderstand MS Access, I am using subforms. People (the table shown above) is a subform of household (it's a table of the people in a household, due to the one to many relationship between households and people), and the Ethnicity/Income tables are subforms of the person form, which is further a subform of the Household form.

Comment: You are using a subdatasheet rather than a subform. I agree it is not very clear. Here is an image of a form/subform http://allenbrowne.com/graphics/LibraryForm0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would built 3 grids using continues forms, or 3 forms in data sheet view.

You then create a 4 form, and drop in the above 3 forms.

In the master form (which is now a subform), in the on current event, you
place the following command to make the child forms follow this form.

me.Parent.Child1.Requery
me.Parent.Child2.Requery.

In the link child/master settings for child 1, you place:

linkChildFields      main_id        (whatever is the name of the field in
this sub-form that is used to relate back to the parent table)
LinkMasterFields    [MasterForm].[form].[ID]

In the link child/master settings for child 2 form you place

linkChildFields      main_id        (whatever is the name of the field in
this sub-form that is used to relate back to the parent table)
LinkMasterFields    [MasterForm].[form].[ID]   ("masterForm" is the name of
the contorl you used to hold the master form).

The "many" to many screen looks like this:

[image]

The above is a classic accounting or funds distribution in which we take an amount like $50 and distribute the amount over many accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a structure problem, actually.  Wouldn't it be more efficient to base your property accessory tables (dietary restrictions, occupations, etc) - properties that a single person might possess a number of - on your personal information table, perhaps keyed to a individual ID of some sort (employers often use SSNs, as they are unique - though in your case, you might just make them auto-generating).  Items like Ethnicity, and position within a household are something an individual possesses one of, and would be something you could indeed place within your personal information table.

With proper structuring, and the right query work - you can have a form that allows you to edit all of these properties on a family while keeping referential integrity.

Comment: Position within a household is actually a property of the individual currently, it just links to another table (many to one) for the sake of sanity. Unfortunately individuals in this setting actually can have more than one Ethnicity (since the paper forms involved are titled "Check all that apply"), so there's no way around these many to many relationships.